# looking for examples of SVG graphics in Leaflet popups

Tags: svg, d3.js, leaflet

I am building a map with Leaflet and D3. I am bringing in the points as a Leaflet layer. I would like to bind popups for these points that include SVG graphics in the popup.

Has anyone seen examples of this? I think it is possible since HTML is allowed in the popup but I would like to find a working example.

Thank you,

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible. Use HTML in your popup as you normally would. For instance, you could add a `<div class="popupGraph"/>` element in your popup. Then simply use JavaScript as you normally would to display whatever you want in that element.

Edit: I'll add a bit more of an example. I have a very different look/feel for a Popup, so what I did was extend my own.

```
myPopup = L.Popup.extend({ ... });
```

When I initialize the popup, I add a wrapper for a div that I'll inflate with JavaScript Graph API later (I use JQuery Sparklines http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/).

```
this._graphContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myGraph', this.container);
```

Then I can treat this like any other graph.

```
$(this._graphContainer).sparkline({ /*my options here*/ });
```

This will display a live, updating graph in my popup.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'm giving this a try. Do you happen to have a working example of this? 

Lee

Comment: I can't post my specific source, but it's nothing special. Take a look at the Leaflet.js source code. The method you will be most concerned with is `_initLayout` in the `L.Popup` object. You can see where all of the DOM elements are created for the popup when this code is called. Set a breakpoint there and note the behavior. Use `L.DomUtil.create` to create DOM elements, to add to the `container`. In your code, you can create a DOM elements for your `graphContainer` like I described in my answer. Once you create that container, you can treat it as you would any normal graph.