# adding inline SVG to a leaflet popup from within R

Tags: javascript, r, svg, leaflet

The response to the following question suggests that it is possible to add SVG to leaflet popups: [looking for examples of SVG graphics in Leaflet popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570614/looking-for-examples-of-svg-graphics-in-leaflet-popups)

Here is another example by way of: [Making a graph inside a leaflet popup using geoJson data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465089/making-a-graph-inside-a-leaflet-popup-using-geojson-data)

However, my following attempt to from the R wrapper for leaflet fails:

```
library(magrittr)
library(leaflet)

content <- paste(sep = '<body>'
                 ,'<svg height="100" width="100">'
                 ,'<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />'
                 ,'Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.'
                 ,'</svg>'
                 ,'</body>'
)


leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298
            ,47.597131
            ,content
            ,options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

**Question: Is it possible to add SVG to leaflet popups from within R?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `content` is not right because by using `sep = "<body>"`, you have inserted a `<body>` tag in between each of your other tags in the `paste()` call. Using `\n` as the separator instead, the SVG in the popup works for me:

```
content <- paste('<body>'
                 ,'<svg height="100" width="100">'
                 ,'<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />'
                 ,'Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.'
                 ,'</svg>'
                 ,'</body>', sep = "\n"
)
```

Comment: thanks for this! i was not paying attention when I worked up this "toy" example for a larger problem I was having. glad to see that inline svg is possible though. I suspect I have a similar formatting problem in my larger problem.